# Using pdo prepare with dates and UNION returns no results (mysql)

Tags: mysql, date, pdo, prepared-statement, union

I have a prepared request with PDO which returns no results.  It looks like the problem comes from the date formatting or something.  I tried it using same values in phpmyadmin and everything works fine and results show up, but once in prepared statement it wont work. I use PDO::PARAM_STR to define dates.

I havent found an example using UNION and DATE in a prepared statement.

```
$sql2 = "(
  SELECT 
  SUM((IF(glMonthNow.debit IS NULL, 0, glMonthNow.debit))-(if(glMonthNow.credit IS NULL,0,glMonthNow.credit))) as computeMonthNow,

  SUM(case when glMonthNow.debit IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as debitCount,
  SUM(case when glMonthNow.credit IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as creditCount

  FROM tblgeneralledger_2014 AS glMonthNow
  WHERE glMonthNow.accounts_list_id=:account_id 
  AND trs_desc <> 'efa'
  AND glMonthNow.system_date>=:startMonthDate 
  AND glMonthNow.system_date<:endMonthDate
  )

  UNION 

  (
  SELECT 
  SUM((IF(glMonthNow.debit IS NULL, 0, glMonthNow.debit))-(if(glMonthNow.credit IS NULL,0,glMonthNow.credit))) as computeMonthNow,

  SUM(case when glMonthNow.debit IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as debitCount,
  SUM(case when glMonthNow.credit IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as creditCount

  FROM tblgeneralledger_2015 AS glMonthNow
  WHERE glMonthNow.accounts_list_id=:account_id AND trs_desc <> 'efa' 
  AND glMonthNow.system_date>=:startMonthDate AND glMonthNow.system_date<:endMonthDate
)";

$sql2 = $mysql_dbh->prepare($sql2);
$sql2->bindParam(":account_id",$account->id);
$sql2->bindParam(":startMonthDate",$startMonthDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql2->bindParam(":endMonthDate",$endMonthDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql2->execute();
$data2=$sql2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Example of value used:
account_id = 644;
startMonthDate = '2014-12-01';
endMonthDate= '2014-12-01'
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: where are the closing quotes? (") and semi-colon?

Comment: @Vakarm: $account->id is a typo? I think is $account_id. right?

Comment: $account->id is the parameter "id" of the object $account.

Comment: @Vakarm: $startMonthDate is already string so you don't have to use PDO::PARAM_STR.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Academia. 
I still get the same result. Maybe I should give up using prepared-statement for this one.

Comment: @Vakarm: try using this before giving up:) bindParam (":startMonthDate", strtotime (date ($startMonthDate)), PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: @Vakarm never give up see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placeholders need to be unique, unless you have emulation turned on.
So do not duplicate have seperate for each `:startMonthDate`, `:startMonthDate2` and so on.

Then bind to the same variable, that is fine. And you should avoid re-assigning `$sql2` vairiable, that is misleading:

```
$stmt= $mysql_dbh->prepare($sql2);
$stmt->bindParam(":account_id",$account->id);
$stmt->bindParam(":startMonthDate",$startMonthDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":endMonthDate",$endMonthDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":startMonthDate2",$startMonthDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":endMonthDate2",$endMonthDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$data2=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But for sure you should have gotten an error, which makes me wonder if you enabled error mode to exception, place the following line after connection:

```
$mysql_dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```